# How to add rows and submit form with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code...

```
<h3>Guests</h3>
<form class="form-inline">
    <fieldset>                                  
        <label class="control-label" for="input01">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="input-small" id="input01">                            
        <label class="control-label" for="input01">&nbsp;&nbsp;Middle Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="input-small" id="input01">
        <label class="control-label" for="input01">&nbsp;&nbsp;Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="input-small" id="input01">
        <label class="control-label" for="input01">&nbsp;&nbsp;Birthday:</label>
            <input type="text" class="input-small" id="input01">>                   
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I would like to be able to add a button that says "Add more", and let that add a new row of elements, eventually saving the form to a database.  If I add a button that adds a row (this needs to add a record to the database.  for records that are changed, I want to update the record in the database).

So the question, multi-parted is:

1. When they click on the "add more" button, I assume this is the best
   time to add a record to the database.  And then when I save the
   form, I loop through and update all the records in the form.  Or are
   there other ideas?
2. The main point: is there an example somewhere that someone can suggest as to how to loop through and perform the update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that saving the values to the database at the same time is not a good idea and think once again  what are you trying here. When someone clicks "**ADD MORE**" you will have new rows then you add those rows value in the database  But what about the initial ones...

may be this will help

```
    <label class="control-label" for="input01">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="input-small" id="input01" name="firstname[]">                            
    <label class="control-label" for="input01">&nbsp;&nbsp;Middle Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="input-small" id="input01" name="middlename[]">
    <label class="control-label" for="input01">&nbsp;&nbsp;Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="input-small" id="input01" name="lastname[]">
    <label class="control-label" for="input01">&nbsp;&nbsp;Birthday:</label>
        <input type="text" class="input-small" id="input01" name=birthday[]>
```

now save the fields you want to appear when the button is clicked in a js var

> var extras = $('fieldset').clone();

then

> $(".yourAddButton").click(function(){
>        $("form").append(extras);
>   });

at last dont forget to have the submit button to submit the form .

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest that the clicking on the "add more" button is
    **not** the best time to add a record to the database. Imagine someone clicking on the button and not actually fill out the row.
    It's cool that you want to get all fancy with your form and provide
    a more interactive user experience, but don't detract from "forms
    101": Have a "submit/save" button. Validate before saving into the
    database. The logic is pretty simple: You'll need the row's ID
    hidden somewhere (probably a hidden text field). The logic goes
    something like, "I have received a $_POST. I have checked that the
    required data is present and OK. Do I have an ID? Yes: Update. No:
    Insert."